# Monte Carlo method to get an approximation to these probabilities deck

Tags: c, algorithm, montecarlo

Use a struct to define a card as an enumerated member that is its suit value and a short that is its pips value.

Write a function that randomly shuffles the deck. Monte Carlo method to get an approximation to these probabilities

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// Define Suit Name of Deck

typedef enum deckName
{
    CLUBS = 0,
    DIAMONDS,
    HEARTS,
    SPADES
} dName;

//Only for name printing purpose.

char *suit[] = {"CLUBS", "DIAMONDS", "HEARTS", "SPADES"};

char *suitVal[] = {"ACE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", "JACK", "QUEEN", "KING"};

//define Struct deck.

struct deck
{
    /* data */
    //define deck name
    dName name;
    short pipe;
};


//Generate Deck with 7 size

void getHandDeck();

//Generate Randaom Number with given size.

int shufflIndex(int size);

//Search Deck Pattern with give suit and pipe.

int searchDeckPattern(int name[], int val[]);

//define counter.

static int NOPAIR = 0;

static int ONEPAIR = 0;

static int TWOPAIR = 0;

static int THREEKIND = 0;

static int FULLHOUSE = 0;

static int FOURKIND = 0;


//shuffle deck.

int main()
{

    getHandDeck();
    printf("Total NO PAIR:  %d\n", NOPAIR);
    printf("Total ONE PAIR:  %d\n", ONEPAIR);
    printf("Total TWO PAIR:  %d\n", TWOPAIR);
    printf("Total THREE KIND:  %d\n", THREEKIND);
    printf("Total FULL HOUSE:  %d\n", FULLHOUSE);
    printf("Total FOUR KIND:  %d\n", FOURKIND);
    return 0;
}

//this function Shuffle index of given size.
int shufflIndex(int size)
{
    //num define randowm numer of size.
    int num = 0;
    num = rand() % size;
    return num;
}

//this function get Deck of 7 size , and Search Deck Pattern
void getHandDeck()
{

    //get random index for enum.
    int suitValIndex = 0, suitNameIndex = 0;
    //counter number of suit and pipe in deck.
    int name[4] = {0};
    int value[13] = {0};

    struct deck *d = malloc(sizeof(struct deck) * 7);

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        suitValIndex = shufflIndex(13);
        suitNameIndex = shufflIndex(4);
        name[suitNameIndex] = name[suitNameIndex] + 1;
        value[suitValIndex] = value[suitValIndex] + 1;
        //for printing purpose....
        d[i].name = suitNameIndex;
        d[i].pipe = suitValIndex;
        printf("%s  %s \n", suit[suitNameIndex], suitVal[suitValIndex]);
    }

    /*
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", name[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", value[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    */

    //Search pattern in deck.
    searchDeckPattern(name, value);
    printf("\n");
    free(d);
}

//This function search pattern in deck size of 7.
int searchDeckPattern(int name[], int val[])
{

    bool flg = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){

        if ((name[i] == 4 || name[i] == 3)){
            //FullHouse Flush.
            //Three or Four card of same suit.
            FULLHOUSE++;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++){

        if ((val[j] == 4 || val[j] == 3) && (ONEPAIR > 1 || TWOPAIR > 1)){
            //FullHouse Flush.
            //Three or Four card of same value.
            FULLHOUSE++;
        }

        if (val[j] == 2 && flg){
            //One Pair
            //contains two cards of one rank
            ONEPAIR++;
            flg = true;
        }

        if (val[j] == 3){
            //three Pair
            //contains three cards of one rank and two cards of two other ranks
            THREEKIND++;
        }

        if (val[j] == 4){
            //Four Pair
            //contains quads, is a hand that contains four cards of one rank amd other cards of other rank.
            FOURKIND++;
        }

        if (val[j] == 2 && flg == false){
            //TWO Pair
            //contains two cards of one rank, two cards of another rank and other third rank
            TWOPAIR++;
            flg = false;
        }

        if (val[j] == 1){
            //No Match Pair.
            NOPAIR++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If this is a working answer can mark it as one and ideally provide some outputs as well. If it is not an answer but additional code, edit your question and put the code there. Thank you.

Comment: sample output.

SPADES  THREE 
CLUBS  FOUR 
CLUBS  EIGHT 
HEARTS  KING 
CLUBS  ACE 
DIAMONDS  QUEEN 
SPADES  QUEEN 

Total NO PAIR:  5
Total ONE PAIR:  1
Total TWO PAIR:  0
Total THREE KIND:  0
Total FULL HOUSE:  1
Total FOUR KIND:  0